# (Javascript) | interact.js pinch zoom on multiple div with same classes not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to use interact.js to have some elements that I could pinch-zoom around.
But I have a problem because when I duplicate the element it stop to work.

As you can see from the snippet here, I have two identical elements named `class=gesture-area` and, inside of each, there's a `div` with `class=scale-element`.

I'm able to pinch-zoom only on the first of them using `document.querySelector()`.

I don't konw how to enable all of the divs to the pinch-zoom.

How can I be able to use this script on multiple `divs` on the page?

```js
function dragMoveListener (event) {
  var target = event.target
  // keep the dragged position in the data-x/data-y attributes
  var x = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-x')) || 0) + event.dx
  var y = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-y')) || 0) + event.dy

  // translate the element
  target.style.webkitTransform =
    target.style.transform =
      'translate(' + x + 'px, ' + y + 'px)'

  // update the posiion attributes
  target.setAttribute('data-x', x)
  target.setAttribute('data-y', y)
}

// this is used later in the resizing and gesture demos
window.dragMoveListener = dragMoveListener
  
  
  
var angleScale = {
  angle: 0,
  scale: 1
}
//var gestureArea = document.getElementsByClassName('gesture-area')
var gestureArea = document.querySelector('.gesture-area')
//var scaleElement = document.getElementsByClassName('scale-element')
var scaleElement = document.querySelector('.scale-element')
var resetTimeout

console.log(gestureArea);

interact(gestureArea)
  .gesturable({
    onstart: function (event) {
      angleScale.angle -= event.angle

      clearTimeout(resetTimeout)
      scaleElement.classList.remove('reset')
    },
    onmove: function (event) {
      // document.body.appendChild(new Text(event.scale))
      var currentAngle = event.angle + angleScale.angle
      var currentScale = event.scale * angleScale.scale

      scaleElement.style.webkitTransform =
      scaleElement.style.transform =
        'rotate(' + currentAngle + 'deg)' + 'scale(' + currentScale + ')'

      // uses the dragMoveListener from the draggable demo above
      dragMoveListener(event)
    },
    onend: function (event) {
      angleScale.angle = angleScale.angle + event.angle
      angleScale.scale = angleScale.scale * event.scale

      //resetTimeout = setTimeout(reset, 1000)
      scaleElement.classList.add('reset')
    }
  })
  .draggable({ onmove: dragMoveListener })

function reset () {
  scaleElement.style.webkitTransform =
    scaleElement.style.transform =
    'scale(1)'

  angleScale.angle = 0
  angleScale.scale = 1
}
```

```css
.pinchzoomarea {

    display: flex;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    margin-bottom: 9px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #a80000;
    }
    
    .gesture-area {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.scale-element {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    touch-action: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    background-size: cover;
    cursor: move;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/interactjs@latest/dist/interact.min.js"></script>

<div class="pinchzoomarea">
  <div id="gesture-area" class="gesture-area">
    <div id="scale-element" class="scale-element"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="pinchzoomarea">
  <div class="gesture-area">
    <div class="scale-element"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

ok solved,
needed to change the selector to this: `event.target.parentElement.children[0];`
Now the JS is:

```
function dragMoveListener (event) {
  var target = event.target

  // keep the dragged position in the data-x/data-y attributes
  var x = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-x')) || 0) + event.dx
  var y = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-y')) || 0) + event.dy

  // translate the element
  target.style.webkitTransform =
    target.style.transform =
      'translate(' + x + 'px, ' + y + 'px)'

  // update the posiion attributes
  target.setAttribute('data-x', x)
  target.setAttribute('data-y', y)
}

// this is used later in the resizing and gesture demos
window.dragMoveListener = dragMoveListener



var angleScale = {
  angle: 0,
  scale: 1
}


interact('.gesture-area')
  .gesturable({
    onstart: function (event) {
      angleScale.angle -= event.angle

      clearTimeout(resetTimeout)
      //scaleElement.classList.remove('reset')
    },
    onmove: function (event) {
      var currentAngle = event.angle + angleScale.angle
      var currentScale = event.scale * angleScale.scale
      var close = event.target.parentElement.children[0];
      var scaleElement = event.target.parentElement.children[1];
      console.log(scaleElement)

      scaleElement.style.webkitTransform =
      scaleElement.style.transform =
        'rotate(' + currentAngle + 'deg)' + 'scale(' + currentScale + ')'

      dragMoveListener(event)
    },
    onend: function (event) {
      var close = event.target.parentElement.children[0];
      var scaleElement = event.target.parentElement.children[1];
      angleScale.angle = angleScale.angle + event.angle
      angleScale.scale = angleScale.scale * event.scale

      resetTimeout = setInterval(() => {

      }, interval);(reset, 1000)



    }


  })
  .draggable({ onmove: dragMoveListener })

  function reset () {
      scaleElement.style.webkitTransform =
        scaleElement.style.transform =
        'scale(1)'

      angleScale.angle = 0
      angleScale.scale = 1
      }
  setInterval
```